# How can I search and copy files using a .bat file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I would like to search for all .txt files from a computer drive and copy them to a specific folder using a batch file.

Comment: You're talking about recursing through all directories on the drive and copying all .txt files to a single folder on another drive?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch script will help you achieve what you're after

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P drive="Enter the drive letter"
FOR /R "%drive%:\" %%G IN (*.txt) DO (
ECHO COPY %%G W:\RestorePoint\%%~nG
)
```

I'm assuming in this script that the restore directory is "W:\RestorePoint" which is a directory that needs to be created prior to running the script.

Comment: If you felt my answer was helpful please mark it and upvote it :) Thank you